# JAXRS + JerseyTest testing a REST Service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-test-framework

I've created a Rest service with four methods, GET,POST,UPDATE and DELETE. 
These methods make connections to a Database to retrieve and store data.

Now I want to test each method. I've used the Jersey Test Framework for this. And it is working as long as I remove the code what actually makes the call to the database. When I leave the code that makes the call to the database it throws an exception that it could not connect to the database.

EDIT: I have done some research and used dependancy injection. The db calls are moved to a separate class but I'm still doing something wrong.

DatabaseResults. In this class the call to the DB is made.

```
public class DatabaseResults {

private final String getQuery = "SELECT * FROM movies";
private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
private final ArrayList<Movie> jsonList = new ArrayList<>();

public JSONObject getAllMovies() throws SQLException {

    try {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = DatabaseUtility.getDataSource();
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();

        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(getQuery);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            jsonList.add(new Movie(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(3)));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        System.out.println("Could not retrieve a connection");
        connection.rollback();
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("movies", jsonList);

    return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

MoviesResource that contains the REST methods

```
@Path("movies")
public class MoviesResource {

....
private DatabaseResults dbResults = null;

public MoviesResource() {
    this(new DatabaseResults());
}

MoviesResource(DatabaseResults dbr){
     this.dbResults = dbr;

}
....
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllMovies() throws JSONException, SQLException {

    return Response.status(200).entity(dbResults.getAllMovies().toString()).build();
}
```

The Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnit44Runner.class)
public class MovieResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

@Mock
DatabaseResults dbr;  

@Before
public void setup() throws SQLException{
    jsonObject.put("id", "hello");

    when(dbr.getAllMovies()).thenReturn(jsonObject);
}        

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client
        .target("http://localhost:9998/RestServiceMovies/resources");

@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(MoviesResource.class);
}

@Test
public void getAllMoviesTest() throws SQLException {

    String responseGetAllMovies = target("/movies").request().get(String.class);

    Assert.assertTrue("hello".equals(responseGetAllMovies));
}
```

At this moment I can run the tests but still when I test the `getAllMovies()` method it makes a call to the real database instead of returning the `jsonObject`.

I have the feeling that a connection is missing between the mock object and the constructor from the MovieResource class?

Comment: This is harder to test because your REST service is violating the single responsibility principle. If you encapsulate your database logic in another class, then you can easily mock that class to test your REST service in isolation. Another common approach is to through unit tests out the window and just run integration tests; i.e. configure an in-memory database and don't mock anything.

Comment: Ok. So I've encapsulated my database logic in a separate class. I want to mock the data with Mockito but I'm actually not sure how I can say that my `getAllMovies` method should use the mocked class...

Comment: There a few approaches to this. I assume that your REST service has access to some private field, e.g. `moviesDatabase`. You want to mock this object or its methods, so you need some way of telling REST service which `moviesDatabase` to use. Your options are: (1) constructor injection (2) make the field package-private and set it directly (3) use a fancy dependency injection framework like Dagger or Weld.

Comment: please update your question with the database logic being moved to a separate class, so that we have visibility of how we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you register your resource as a class

```
new ResourceConfig(MoviesResource.class)
```

you are telling Jersey to create the instance. If you don't have any DI configured, it will just call the no-arg constructor. In your no-arg constructor, you are just creating the service yourself. It knows nothing about your mock.

What you should do instead is register the resource class as an instance. That way you can pass the mock to the constructor.

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
return new ResourceConfig()
        .register(new MoviesResource(dbr));
```

Don't use the Mockito runner. Instead use the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` method. That way you control when the `@Mock`s are injected. If you use the runner, the injection will not happen in time, as the the `configure` method is called by the framework before the Mockito injection happens.

Comment: Thanks! I've removed the Mockito runner and added the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); return new ResourceConfig().register(new MoviesResource(dbr))` code.

Comment: Your right, it should be `initMocks`, not `init` :-)